# Codeigniter, getting ajax to run on button press

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

My original goal was to get a php file to execute on a button press. I used ajax.  When the javascript was in the view, it worked.

However, I tried to switch the javascript to its own .js file and include it in the header.  It doesn't work anymore.  I am confused.

the model code:

```
public function insert_build($user_id)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO user_structure (str_id, user_id) VALUES ('7', '$user_id')";
    mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
}
```

Something interesting to note here is that when I include $user_id as a value, it completely negates my headertemplate.  As in, it simply doesnt load.  When I replace $user_id with a static value (i.e. '7') it works no problem.

This is my view code :

```
<div id="structures">
    <h1>Build</h1>
    <form name="buildForm" id="buildForm" method="POST">
        <select name="buildID" class="buildClass">
        <option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Build a Structure</option>
<?php foreach ($structures as $structure_info): ?>
    <option name='<?php echo $structure_info['str_name'] ?>' value='<?php echo $structure_info['str_id'] ?>' data-icon='<?php echo $structure_info['str_imageloc'] ?>' data-html-text='<?php echo $structure_info['str_name'] ?><i>
        <?php echo $structure_info['timebuildmins'] ?> minutes<br><?php echo $structure_info['buy_gold'] ?> gold</i>'><?php echo $structure_info['str_name'] ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
        <div id="buildSubmit">
            <input id ="btnSubmit" class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Heres my .js file :

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php $this->structure_model->insert_build($user_id) ?>",         //the script to call to get data          
    data: "",                        //you can insert url arguments here to pass to api.php
                                        //for example "id=5&parent=6"
    dataType: 'json',                //data format      
    success: function(data)          //on receive of reply
    {
    alert("success!");
    } 
    });
});
```

I am almost sure I know the problem:  That `structure_model->insert_build($user_id) ?>` doesn't work when its outside the view.  Though, I dont know the alternative.

I excluded the header file.  I confirmed that the .js file is indeed being directed to the correct path.

Could someone please explain the correct way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you move your javascript to a .js that is being directly accessed by the browser? I.E: If you view source, so you see the `<?php ... ?>` in the javascript code?

To me, it sounds as though the PHP is not getting parsed. If this is not the case, then can you please clarify.

If you need to include PHP variables in your javascript, you should use CI to generate the JS page for inclusion. You can even create a View that is purely JS and call it like a normal page.

Otherwise, if you want to seperate the JS from CI, you should reference JS variables instead of PHP. Then in your CI page somewhere, define them with a `<script>var jsVar = <?php echo phpvar(); ?></script>` tag.

Comment: It seems so obvious now.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem! and like I said, you can make a view with nothing but JS content, and even name it something.js.php and have it look like an actual .js file on the server from the point of view of the user. GL

Answer (score 0):

When you move the js file to it's own file, php variables will not be accessible anymore. You can either move the js code back to your view file, or fetch the url through javascript. See below for example.

HTML:

```
<div id="structures">
  <h1>Build</h1>
  <form name="buildForm" id="buildForm" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php $this->structure_model->insert_build($user_id) ?>" />
    <!-- Rest of your code -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
  var form_url = $(this).closest('form').find('input[name=url]').val();
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: form_url,         //the script to call to get data          
    data: "",                        //you can insert url arguments here to pass to api.php
                                    //for example "id=5&parent=6"
    dataType: 'json',                //data format      
    success: function(data)          //on receive of reply
    {
      alert("success!");
    } 
  });
});
```